# How to add a mask over camera using react-native-document-scanner

Tags: react-native

I am working on a react-native app, I'm using [react-native-document-scanner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-document-scanner-plugin) because I need to detect documents. However, I need to add a **mask** to it like we have for QR code scanners. Is there a way to simply implement that or is there a package allowing it? (react-native-camera does not suit my needs)

reference:

[mask on top of camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHV7Q.png)